# How to present some regions in raster (matrix) with conditions from another raster?

Tags: r, matrix, raster

I have two matrix  r and r2. I would like to plot  r , this simply can be done using

```
       plot (r)
```

But I would like to mark all values higher than 20 in `r2` in the plot of `r`.
a reproducible example:

```
   library(raster)
  r <- raster(nrows=10, ncols=10)
  r <- setValues(r, 1:ncell(r))
  r2 <- raster(nrows=10, ncols=10)
 r2 <- setValues(r2, 1:ncell(r))
 plot(r)
```

This will poroduce this:

[image]

I would like to mark in this plot all areas where r2 higher than 20 in red for example.Thanks for your ideas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this for example:

```
set.seed(1)
library(raster)
r <- raster(nrows=5, ncols=5)
r <- setValues(r, 1:ncell(r))
r2 <- raster(nrows=5, ncols=5)
r2 <- setValues(r2, round(runif(ncell(r),10,20)),2)
## 100 here as a value that don't exist in range of values(r)
## and it gives the blue value
r[r2<15] <- '100'
## I plot the 3 to see check the result
plot(stack(r,r2,r2<15))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks but the scale of r changes. I do not want the scale of r to change. Keep r as it is but mark regions with values higher than 20 in red for example.

Comment: you can just a value in the range of r. For example `r[r2<15] <- 18`. and you plot with something like `plot(r,col=rainbow(ncells(r))`

Comment: yes but I wanted it to be distinguished!the thing is how you plot the final r with the same scale and ignoring pixels with values of 100 (or give specific colour for pixels with values of 100)

Comment: to ignore use `r[r2<15] <- NA`  and plot(r) but to set a color you should use something like `grid.raster` you can see an example [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15121290/how-to-set-color-of-inserted-image-in-r/15122200#15122200).

Comment: r[r2<15] <- NA will mix them with existing NAs.

Comment: @sacvf either you set your missing values to a some value (say -1) or you wait a better solution.